# Use regex to remove character ' from string between two other characters.

Tags: python, regex

I have a strings that is a result from GridSearch, like this:

```
str({'loss': 'log', 'max_iter': 5, 'tol': None})
```

and I want to receive (in order to fill it as arguments in function):

```
" loss= 'log', max_iter = 5, tol = None "
```

I don't know what would be the best way to convert?

1. Use regex to remove only ' from "keys". So between "{" and ":" or "," and ":". Or maybe two ' to the left of ":".
2. eval(*string*) to build a dictionary and then convert somehow key-value pairs. I was trying something like:

this

```
for keys in eval(str({'loss': 'log', 'max_iter': 5, 'tol': None})):
    print('{}={}'.format(keys, dicto[keys]))
```

I would certainly prefer regex but all my tries are useless.

Comment: Note that if you have a dictionary of your arguments, you can pass them to a function like so:  `func(**dict_of_args)` without all of the messy string manipulation.

Comment: And don't use regex for this. It WILL be wrong, and it will break. It's easier, and safer to convert to a dictionary first. You should be able to use `import json` `json.load(str)` but I'm not fluent in Python and can't test that.

Comment: @ScottHunter I had error in my code, therefore your solution was good for me.